# positioning (centring vertically) span's inside div

Tags: html, css

I have 3 spans:

```css
.see-more{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.see-more .see-more-text{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: -2px;
}

.see-more .fa-angle-right{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:-6px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="see-more">
        <a href="ground-stabilisation">
            <span class="see-more-text">see more</span
            <span class="fal fa-angle-right"></span>
            <span class="fal fa-angle-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

efects of this code looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to lower the angle-right icons so that they are in the middle of the "see more" text, unfortunately in all tries always the whole div is moving , not the elements inside. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try margin-top :20px (try to set the number as required) in fa-angle-right css